# Store and Get Images in Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I need your help. I need to save a picture from the camera into an ImageView. When I open the App, the picture has to appear there but I don't have an idea how that works. I´m a beginner so I would really appreciate your help/tips :)
Thank you.

To be more specific, I take a picture from my phone, and the picture appears, but when I close the App it is not there anymore. Should I use NSUser Defaults???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save simple photo, you can use UserDefaults. You need to convert the image to NSData and then you will be able to save in UserDefaults. Here's the example code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load saved image
    loadImageFromUserDefaults()
}

private func loadImageFromUserDefaults() {
    guard let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "image_data") as NSData? else {
        print("No image saved")
        return
    }
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
    imageView.image = image
}

private func saveImageToUserDefaults(image: UIImage) {
    guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) as NSData? else {
        print("Failed to convert image")
        return
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "image_data")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

@IBAction func selectPhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        saveImageToUserDefaults(image: image)
        loadImageFromUserDefaults()
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it shows the image in the "ImageView" every time I run the App.I really appreciate your help! :D

Comment: Welcome, sure no problem!